# how to translate an html from Arabic page to English

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap Website with html webpages and no back-end
I want to know how would I translate from Arabic to English
Knowing that I have the translations of all the content "no need for Translating tools"
is there is any way to **map the Arabic sentences to the English one ** when clicking the English button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better to create content in english.
also u can change text direction using ltr property. in browser also support translation but the translations are not accurate or meaning may be change.
please refer css direction property for text direction for languages

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please do not give link only anwsers, they are not allowed on SO. You may give that as a comment as soon as your earned the priveledge for it.

Comment: do you mean by that to write the whole code again but in English and fix the direction?  cuz I thought of that but I said maybe there's a way to just map the words

Comment: u dont have any backend right ???

Comment: yes I don't have any backend

Comment: so u should create another html page. once u click the english,  html will show. there is no other way

Comment: ok , thank you so much @niya 